# How to return and clear a list?

Tags: java, performance, list, return, return-value

I've wondered if there is a more elegant approach to return an attribute and change/"reset" its value. This is the way I've been doing it by now:

```
[...]

final List<T> copyOfOriginal = new ArrayList<T>(original);
original.clear();

return copyOfOriginal;

[...]
```

Do I really have to copy the whole list?

Comment: If you are trying to clone an Arraylist, then this is fine. What is the actual problem you are working around that requires this?

Comment: @cricket_007 I wanted to return and clear the list without cloning it... that's achieved quite easy (see NPE's answer)

Comment: What is `original`? Is it method parameter, or field in your class (or both)?

Comment: @Pshemo it's the list I wan't to return and clear

Comment: "list I wan't to return and clear" means that you want to return empty list which is not what your code shows. I asked previous question because if `original` is parameter of some method like `List<T> cloneAndClear(List<T> original)` and you will use it like `List<T> newList = cloneAndClear(someList);` then `someList` passed as argument will not be cleared with NPE solution since it only swaps *local* references (since Java is pass-by-value). So context matters here and should be clarified in question.

Comment: @Pshemo sorry I was a little bit unclear there. I wan't to return the list `original` (which in this case is an attribute) with all its entries and clear the original list "afterwards". Since it isn't possible to do anything after the return statement I've always copied the original list first, cleared the original and then returned the copy as seen in the code I provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In many cases one can simply replace the list with a new empty one while returning the original reference:

```
final List<T> ret = original;
original = new ArrayList<T>();
return ret;
```

The caveat here is that this changes the original references. If there are multiple copies of it, this might require extra care.

Comment: yep that's quite simple... how could I not have come up with this myself :P